# Layout using percentages, but with minimum and maximum widths for sidebars, etc

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, css-float

I am trying to figure out how to make a layout, where there's a **Main** area, containing the core content of the page, and a **Sidebar**, containing areas for navigation, searching, and more. See illustration below.

[image: layout-sidebar-width-min-width-max-width]

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.1 (http://getbootstrap.com/) with a custom theme. The design is fully responsive on most pages, with a few exceptions. On smartphones and small screen devices, where space is scarce, the sidebar will collapse into an expandable menu, but that is not a concern here.

My ambition is:

- The width of the **Main** area should adjust automatically, i.e. with screen zoom and re-sizing. Though, with `min-width: 320px`.
- The width of the **Sidebar** should be `width: 18%`, though, with `min-width: 300px;` and `max-width: 420px;`.

So far, I have tried obtaining this result using pure `div` tags, but nothing fulfills my demands.

- **Floating divs:** I attempted using floating `div` tags for the **sidebar** and margin on the **main** element (see: http://jsfiddle.net/euxc0593/1/). However, this turned out not to be viable, since a `clear: both` inside one of the divs would also clear both sides outside the element, *unless* `overflow: hidden` is specified. However, `overflow: hidden` on said `div` tags is an unacceptable limitation, since it will cut off e.g. `box-shadow`, borders, and custom tooltips contained within the `div`. Also, my personal preference and experience is that `float` is evil, except when used on images to wrap text nicely around them. Of course this is diligently used by various Grid Systems (e.g. Bootstrap's and http://960.gs/), but those are commonly made for static-width websites and clearly show their weaknesses when used for fully responsive designs with the tiniest twists. It's an "either/or" predicament.
- **inline-block**: I also attempted using `display: inline-block`. However, this is also full of small annoying quirks. E.g. an `inline-block` will technically be considered text, and so there is spacing between the blocks like there would be between text characters (see: http://jsfiddle.net/utxvkwtc/1/). To fix this, the parent element must have `font-size: 0;` specified. However, then `font-size` must be re-specified on the `inline-block` elements. But now the inheritance of the `font-size` from `body` is broken, which is undesirable (see: http://jsfiddle.net/cnqegdxx/2/). Also, we cannot specify `min-width` or `max-width` on these elements, as that will cause the elements to sometimes appear in incorrect positions, e.g. on new lines.
- **Absolute/realtive positioning**: Another attempt was using `position: relative` and `position: absolute`. However, that - again - is not desireable since I don't want other elements to necessarily be positioned relative to the parent, e.g the **Sidebar**.

And so, I have now ended up at a point where I've started using `table`. I'm not proud of it, but it seems it is the only viable solution, since flex boxes are not yet fully supported - or even working correctly - in many browsers (Say "Hi," Opera and Safari).

Going back to the illustration and ambitions listed above. If using a `table`, how may this be done so that the default `width: 18%` is respected as well as the `min-width: 300px;` and `max-width: 420px;`?

- My attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx1q8oxh/1/ (values are changed slightly to fit better inside the JSFiddle window)

The `max-width` is not being respected by the `td.sidebar`, since this property won't work unless the table is `table-layout: fixed`;

If you have an awesome solution I am very interested! Especially if you can achieve this using `div` tags, without introducing Javascript code! :)

Thanks in advance.

**TL;DR:** I want a sidebar in a layout, which has a percentage width, but within a `min-width` and `max-width` in pixels.

Comment: Mixing `width`, `max-width` and `min-width` is perfectly acceptable...you can use all three properties on the same element. What I think your question is really is "How Do I Get the Main Element to Adjust?" ...No?

Comment: @Paulie_D: (1) I know said properties are acceptable. But a `td` element doesn't inherently respect `min-width` or `max-width`. Even `width` is iffy, since the contents of a cell may actually distort the width of the cell. (2) Well, not entirely. This is just one layout type. Another layout has a sidebar on both left and right sides. The Sidebars should behave alike. What's left over is the Main content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS tables (not HTML ones) and mix the various properties as I mentioned in the comments.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 18%;
  max-width: 420px;
  min-width: 300px;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #f06d06;
}
main {
  display: table-cell;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <main></main>
</div>
```

Comment: (1) `max-width` is not being respected. That's the catch which is causing my headache. Try testing it out by setting `width: 80%` on the sidebar or something similar. (2) Using CSS instead of HTML doesn't make much of a difference. The only difference is that you can use less HTML tags, but need to specify more CSS, which of course from a performance point of view is desirable since less data has to be transferred.

Comment: Added..table layout fixed...I think that should fix it.

Comment: Even with `table-layout: fixed`, the  `width` property trumps `max-width`.

Comment: OK...what about - http://jsfiddle.net/wLxeers7/1/ Oh. but you don't like floats. I've used a quick clearfix but there are others that don't rely on `overflow` hidden. I think you need to solve the layout issue first, then worry about styling. Or perhaps **flexbox**?

Comment: (1) Nope. Floats are evil, and as mentioned `overflow: hidden` is not welcome at this party. (2) Flexible boxes, sadly, are not viable, since <=IE9 don't support this: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: So use another clearfix - I used overflow hidden for speed. If you won't use floats then perhaps a grid system is not for you....pretty much all of them use it.

Comment: I appreciate your help! :) Thing is, when using floating elements the only working, reliable clearfix is `overflow: hidden;` - as you provided in your example. And that is what I want to avoid, cf the description in my original post.

Comment: Actually there are several other very reliable methods...floating the parent will work or there's this - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/